# PlayFramework: CRUD and sorted lists

Tags: java, sorting, playframework, crud

I've just read about `CRUD` system of PlayFramework and decided to write simple example, just two classes `Group` and `User` and decided that a lot of users can be in one group but one user can be just in one group. So, I've used for it `ManyToOne` and `OneToMany` anotations, please take a look to the code below:

```
package models;

import play.db.jpa.Model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

/**
 * @author sergiizagriichuk
 */
@Entity
public class User extends Model {
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;

    @ManyToOne
    public Group group;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return firstName;
    }
}
```

and

```
package models;

import play.db.jpa.Model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OrderBy;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author sergiizagriichuk
 */
@Entity
public class Group extends Model {
    public String groupName;
    public String groupDescription;
    @OneToMany
    @OrderBy("firstName desc")
    public List<User> users;

}
```

For sorting I've tried to use `OrderBy` annotation, and as result nothing :(, I have list of users in additional sorting mode, but I wanna order by `firstName`, Could someone explain me how to sort list using controller for friendly using in `CRUD` mode ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

did you try adding the *mappedBy* attribute in your users list?

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="group")
```

Comment: In this case the list of user just deleted from edit form, and it is not solution for me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what issue it is causing, but in hibernate you need to specify the owner of the relation.. also not sure if it makes a difference but I've always seen "DESC" (with capital letters)

Comment: if the list goes empty it is because you need to set the user group field before saving. If you don't add the "mappedBy" attribute hibernate will generated an additional table because it does not know that "users" and "group" are the two ends of the same relation.

Comment: desc or DESC, I've checked both variants before publish this question, did not work, about empty list,I mean,  list is not empty, list DOES NOT present if I delete mapedBy list is present but not sorted. And question was about it.